# OpenCL kernel float division gives different result

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, opencl, gpu

I have a OpenCL kernel for some computation. I found only one thread gives different result with CPU codes. I am using vs2010 x64 release mode.

By checking the OpenCL codes by some examples, I found some interesting results. Here are the testing examples in kernel codes.

I tested 3 cases in OpenCl kernel, the precision is checked by `printf("%.10f", fval);`

## case 1:

```
float fval = (10296184.0) / (float)(x*y*z);  // which gives result fval = 3351.6225585938

float fval = (10296184.0f) / (float)(x*y*z);  // which gives result fval = 3351.6225585938
```

Variables are: `int x,y, z`

these values are computed by some operations. And their values are x=12, y=16, z=16;

## case 2:

```
float fval = (10296184.0) / (float)(12*16*16); // which gives result fval = 3351.6223144531

float fval = (10296184.0f) / (float)(12*16*16); // which gives result fval = 3351.6223144531
```

## case 3:

However, when I compute the difference of `fval` by using above two expressions, the result is 0 if using `10296184.0`.

`float fval = (10296184.0) / (float)(x*y*z) - (10296184.0) / (float)(12*16*16); // which gives result fval = 0.0000000000`

`float fval = (10296184.0f) / (float)(x*y*z) - (10296184.0f) / (float)(12*16*16); // which gives result fval = 0.0001812663`

Could anyone explain the reason or give me some hints?

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)? These inaccuracies are one reason why I always use `double` (although it suffers the same thing) unless some constraint forces me to use the inferior `float`.

Comment: If you need more precision than that, that's why double-precision FP is a thing on GPUs. It has very little application in rendering.

Comment: Post how the values of `3351.6226, 3351.6223 and 0` were determined.  `printf("%f", ...)`, debugger, etc.

Comment: Key answer is the one given by @chux. It is the missmatch of compile time division vs run time division. Precision differs in both.

Comment: What compiler are you using, what platform, what compiler settings?  What is the result of `fegetround()`?  from `<fenv.h>` What is the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` from `<float.h>`.  Take this info, the answer(s) below, the results of the function and macro and we likely have all the additional info needed.  The larger issue is in [FP broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and how code should be written differently to be less susceptible to small ULP errors.

Comment: Notice that you do not know is the result is _exactly_ 0.0 by using `printf("%.10f", fval);`  You just know it is smaller than 0.00000000005.  Use `e` not `f` instead: `printf("%.10e", fval);`

Answer (score 3):

Some observations:

The two `float` values  differ by 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).  So the results differ by a minimum amount.

```
// Float ULP in the 2's place here
//       v
0x1.a2f3ea0000000p+11 3351.622314... // OP's lower float value 
0x1.a2f3eaaaaaaabp+11 3351.622395... // higher precision quotient
0x1.a2f3ec0000000p+11 3351.622558... // OP's higher float value
```

`(10296184.0) / (float)(12*16*16)` is calculated at *compile* time as is the *closer* result to the expected mathematical answer.

`float fval = (10296184.0) / (float)(x*y*z)` is calculated at *run* time.

Considering  `float` variables being used, surprising that code is doing this division with `double` math.  This is a `double` constant divide by a `double` (which is the promotion of the `float` product) resulting in a `double` quotient, converted to a `float` and then saved.  I'd expect `10296184.0f` - note the `f` - to have been used, then the math could have all been done as `float`s.

C allows different rounding modes denoted by `FLT_ROUNDS`  This may differ at compile time and run time and *may* explain the difference.  Knowing the result of `fegetround()` (The function gets the current rounding direction.) would help.

OP *may* have employed various compiler optimizations that sacrifice precision for speed.

---

C does **not specify the precision** of math operations, yet good to the last ULP should be expected with `* / + - sqrt() modf()` on quality platforms.  I suspect code suffers from a weak math implementation.